# Interpretation of interaction and nested random effects in mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, interaction, interpretation, nested-data

I have two questions:

1. How do I interpret and report the variances of my mixed effect model in lmer?
2. Is this mixed model appropriate for my study?

Set up:

In my study I'm rearing fish in two different environments (one with increased water flow and one without) to see if there is a reduction in among family variance in length. Families (the offspring of 1 male and 1 female) tend to vary in average length and I would like to see if flow can make those averages closer together. So I'm not interested in every fish from every family the same length, rather the range of lengths within each family.

I have 4 tanks in each treatment and individuals from 15 families in each tank. I have lengths and family id for each individual fish.

This is the lmer mixed effects model I'm using:

`test8 <- lmer(length ~ treatment + (1+treatment|family) + (1|treatment/tank), OHRC.dat.fam)`

Where `treatment` is a fixed effect, `(1+treatment|family)` as the interaction between `treatment` and the random effect `family`, and `(1|treatment/tank)` as random effect `tank` nested within `treatment`.

This is the summary output:

```
> summary(test8)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: length ~ treatment + (1 + treatment | family) + (1 | treatment/tank)
   Data: OHRC.dat.fam

REML criterion at convergence: 10766

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.3099 -0.4251  0.1193  0.6400  2.4169 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name          Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 family         (Intercept)   0.42603  0.6527       
                treatmentflow 0.04465  0.2113   0.10
 tank:treatment (Intercept)   0.03785  0.1946       
 treatment      (Intercept)   2.21591  1.4886       
 Residual                     1.83716  1.3554       
Number of obs: 3099, groups:  family, 15; tank:treatment, 8; treatment, 2

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     15.3321     1.5017 3020.6611  10.210   <2e-16 ***
treatmentflow    0.3322     2.1110 3063.1449   0.157    0.875    
---
```

Is this the correct code to use to show my study?

Based on this graph of family mean lengths across treatments I can see there isn't a noticeable difference in the treatments. If anything, the distribution of families looks like it has increased.

[image]

How do I interpret the variances of the random effects to show this?

(This is my first time posting so sorry for any miscommunication and thank you!)